# unix shell script to send mail to user with html table and xl attachment

Tags: shell

Below code is not working together. Individually I am able to send mail with HTML table or able to send mail with attachment but I want to perform both in one single mail. Please help.

Please do not give me a reply to try with uuencode or base64 or mutt as they are not installed in my UNIX system.

Code:

```
(echo "To:"
echo "Cc:"
echo "Subject: Server Status"
echo "Content-Type: text/html"
echo
echo "<html> <head> <title> </title>
<style> table, th, td { border: 1px solid blue; border-collapse: collapse; }
th, td { padding: 5px; } </style> </head> 
<body> <table style='width:100%'>
<tr bgcolor='#808080'> <th>MEMORY</th> <th>DISK</th> <th>CPU</th> </tr>
<tr> <td>"$MEMORY"</td> <td>"$DISK"</td> <td>"$CPU"</td> </tr> </table>
</body></html>") | mail -s "This is the subject" -a /location/*.xlsx mailaddress
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It seems that you forgot to provide your code.

Comment: (echo "To:"
echo "Cc:"
echo "Subject: Server Status"
echo "Content-Type: text/html"
echo
echo "<html>
<head>
<title> </title>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table style='width:100%'>
<tr bgcolor='#808080'>
    <th>MEMORY</th>
    <th>DISK</th>
    <th>CPU</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>"$MEMORY"</td>
    <td>"$DISK"</td>
    <td>"$CPU"</td>
  </tr>  
 </table>
</body></html>") | mail -s "This is the subject" -a /location/*.xlsx mailaddress

Comment: I have just posted the code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in sending a table, but in trying to send a pre-composed HTML text with its content type and an attachement. That is beyond what the Linux `mail` program can do.

The problem lies is the `Content-Type` header. It shall be `text/html` for a mail simply containing a HTML body, but `multipart/mixed` when attachements are included with all parts being correctly encoded according to RFC2046 (in fact RFC2046 to 2049).

As an extension, Linux mail can add attachements to a plain text message (the original mailx program did not do it), but not to a html nor mixed/alternative one.

As you do not want to use more feature rich tools than *mail* to prepare you message, you are facing a dead end: `mail` is simply unable to build this message.

And as `mutt` is a de facto standard in Unix-like world for sending mime messages from a shell, I could not find any other simple tool able to meet your needs. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks Serge for replying to my post. Could you provide me the working code that will send html mail along with xl attachment using mutt or any other rich tool.That will be really helpful.

Comment: Is it possible to send mail with html content along with xl attachment with sendmail command.

Comment: @Ayushi: sendmail is even lower level that mailx so no hope here: something must build the message before sendmail can send it. And for mutt, I am sorry but I know what it is and what it can do but I have never used it so I cannot really help you with it. But I think it is pretty well documented and google should give you hints.